# Как правильно пользоваться медиа запросами, если работаешь с SCSS (вложенные стили)

Tags: sass, scss, media-queries

Здравствуйте. Пишу css на SCSS, но не понял как правильно при этом делать медиа запросы. Наример на выходе я получаю вот такой стиль:

```
.header-navigation {
 width: 70%;
 align-items: baseline;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 position: relative; }
 .header-navigation nav {
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
 width: 660px;
 min-width: 120px; }
 .header-navigation nav #language {
  border: 1px solid #bfd730; }
```

и если мне например надо сделать медиа для *#language* мне приходится дописивать *!important* т.к. такая вложенность блокирует медиа запрос. Правильно ли это?
Медиа стоят в самом низу css, но всеравно блокируются.

Comment: изучите тему "специфичность css"

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу у вас никакого `scss`, то , что вы написали, скомпилируется ровно в тоже самое, это чистый `css`:

```css
.header-navigation {
  width: 70%;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative; 
}
.header-navigation nav {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 660px;
  min-width: 120px; 
}
.header-navigation nav #language {
   border: 1px solid #bfd730;  
}
```

Если вы хотите пользоваться вложенностью `scss`, то запись должна быть хотя бы такой:

```css
.header-navigation{
  width: 70%;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  nav{
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 660px;
    min-width: 120px;
    #language {
      border: 1px solid #bfd730;  
    }
  }
}
```

Чтобы добавить медиа запрос достаточно написать вот так:

```css
.header-navigation{
  width: 70%;
  align-items: baseline;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  @media (max-width:1000px) {
    width: 500px;
  }
  nav{
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 660px;
    min-width: 120px;
    @media (max-width:1000px) {
      width: 500px;
    }
    #language {
      border: 1px solid #bfd730;  
      @media (max-width:1000px) {
       width: 500px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

При такой записи ничего блокироваться не должно.

P.S. Без исходников, точно понять, что у вас не так - невозможно. По результату, могу предположить, что вы задаете не верную очередность медиа запросов. Т.е. если вы идете вверх по размерам то нижние будут перекрываться. И наоборот. Посмотрите в дев тулс. Посмотрите как меняется перекрытие там от изменения на границе заданной медиа точки.

Comment: да, но удобнеё же сделать отдельный файл, или место для медиа запросов куда поместим к примеру все изменения для ширины экрана 1000, а не писать отдельный медиа для кождого элемента

Comment: Все зависит от задачи, если так, то подключайте медиа файл после основных стилей. Это работает. Если не работает у вас, то нужно детально изучить конкретно ваш код.

Comment: @Horchynskyi как и сказал kizoso, вам нужно писать медиа-запросы после основных файлов и в точности повторять дерево классов, выше есть пример в последнем окошке. Если у вас в основном дерево такое - ".header-navigation nav #language", то такое дерево ".header-navigation #language" не перебьёт основное. Как вы заметили я убрал nav во втором.

Comment: @kizoso в вашем ответе я удалил первые два, он хорошо понимает как пишется scss, а вывел он уже скомпилированный css.